# Real-time camera input to Julia-lang

Tags: camera, julia, real-time

**TLDR: How can I achieve low-latency, low-cpu impact webcam aquistition in Julia?**

**edit:** I also posted this on the [julia devs forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/real-time-camera-acquisition-and-processing-howto/20398)

I am new to Julia. I am interested in processing the video feed from a connected webcam, and see what kind of performance I can get out of Julia.

I am working on Linux Ubuntu, 16.04.

The only way I have found to get webcam input through video4linux, is through [VideoIO](https://github.com/JuliaIO/VideoIO.jl), which is working on my system. The video has an unacceptable lag however, of up to 4 seconds. I assume this is given by the buffering of frames by the driver and/or libav (or is it ffmpeg, I dunno). With any camera api worth its name, I should be able to access the latest camera frame acquired... or at least set the size of the queue that Im popping frames from. Seems there is no such option in VideoIO, or maybe I am missing it.

It really is important for me to be able show-case Julia as a high performance language to non-techies... so this lag will ruin the demo I am hoping to put together.

**edit: here is some of the code I have:**

```
module myViewCam
export myView

import VideoIO, ImageView;

function myView() 
        camera = VideoIO.opencamera();
        buf = VideoIO.read(camera);
        guidict = ImageView.imshow(buf);
        while !eof(camera)
            VideoIO.read!(camera, buf);
            ImageView.imshow(guidict["gui"]["canvas"], buf);
            sleep(0.00001);
        end
    end
end
```

Assuming above is content of myViewCam.jl at the Julia prompt (the "REPL"), I type:

```
include("myViewCam.jl");
myViewCam.myView();
```

Note that this is a fix for the function "VideoIO.viewcam()" which does not work out of the box it seems.

On my system, this brings the Julia thread up to about 100% cpu usage, at the beginning of video-stream there is about 4 seconds lag, but this evens out over time, until it lands on about 0.5 seconds lag. There obviously is some queue where frames are popped from.

Comment: Not helpful enough to be an answer, but it looks like VideoIO wraps the `DEFAULT_CAMERA_DEVICE` with `DEFAULT_CAMERA_FORMAT` into an `AVInput` object that works for both files and devices. Try digging through the `AVInput` properties and see/decrease the buffer sizes.Or make sure your other code isnt causing the delay....

Comment: @stillearningsomething, I have looked through the same jl files in the repo of VideoIO. What you suggest could not be done without major investment of time, leading to an update of the api in the end.
regarding my code, there is none to speak of yet. I modified VideoIO.viewcam() in a few different flavors, all yielding the same lag. It is clearly a question of queing frames under the hood, probably in the driver.

Comment: @stillearningsomething, added some code to look at

Comment: I think this will be an important topic to settle. I cannot possibly be the only one who wants do real-time video processing in Julia. I posted this question in the julia discourse forum as well: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/real-time-camera-acquisition-and-processing-howto/20398

Comment: Does OpenCV work? If it does then https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/julia and https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/julia/samples/face_detect_dnn.jl

You'll need to write code to convert to a julia image format. Mainly just permute the last two array dimensions and then use correct colors.

Answer (score 2):

Also see Video4Linux wrapper in Julia which works well with Images.jl:
https://github.com/Affie/Video4Linux.jl

It's not registered yet, but has been around for a while.  It is possible to make this process multithreaded in Julia using SharedArrays.jl, or likely the new Composible Threading model since Julia 1.3.

PS, this vendor specific camera interface package exists too: https://github.com/JuliaCameras/RealSense.jl

Comment: This looks more suited as a comment rather than as an answer

Comment: I dont have the time to test this now, but int the repo referenced there is code example that looks right. And the approach of multi-threading also sounds right.

Comment: I wish someone would do the work of making it efficient (the multithreading part), and then push it upstream to VideoIO.